# Azure Blob delete with encoded URL - Java

Tags: java, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

how would I go about deleting a blob if the URL is encoded.

Sample code

```
`CloudBlockBlob file= container.getBlockBlobReference(path);
 LOGGER.info("file.getUri() ); --> https://<MY_ACCOUNT_INFO>/myFolder/testFile%2520test.txt
 file.delete();
```

I get an exception on delete()- blob not found...even though the CloudBlockBlob is not null....how should I handle this?

Comment: fixed this by doing a URL decode before setting the name for the block refernce

Comment: You could post your solution as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Did a decode on the string I was passing as the name for the blockbob reference and that fixed the issue.

```
path = URLDecoder.decode(path, "UTF-8"); 
CloudBlockBlob file= container.getBlockBlobReference(path);
```